# How to submit all the values of this form as an array and loop through when posting to SQL db?

Tags: php, html, jquery, html-table, form-submit

I have a form with some textinputs which I want to submit to db after filling them out. I am a newbie to PHP so I dont know how to save all the values into an array and submit.

Here is my table wrapped in a form:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
        </br>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div id="wrapper">
                <button type="submit" class="btn" name="add_device">Add devices</button>
            </div>
            </br>
            <table id="ble_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <th>No.</th>                    
                    <th>Serial no.</th>
                    <th>IMEI</th>                    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>                        
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Serial no." class="inputs" name="serial_no" id="serial_no" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder="IMEI" class="inputs lst" name="imei" id="imei" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </form>
```

**jquery for adding new rows when clicking enter:**

```
 var i = $('table tr').length;
    $(document).on('keyup', '.lst', function(e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 13) {
            html = '<tr>';
            html += '<td>' + i + '</td>';
                html += '<td><input type="text" class="inputs" name="serial_no' + i + '" id="serial_no' + i + '" /></td>';
                html += '<td><input type="text" class="inputs lst" name="imei' + i + '" id="imei' + i + '" /></td>';
            html += '</tr>';
            $('table').append(html);
            $(this).focus().select();
            i++;
        }
    });

    $(document).on('keydown', '.inputs', function(e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 13) {
            var index = $('.inputs').index(this) + 1;
            $('.inputs').eq(index).focus();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

**One very important thing to know**: this is a dynamic table, so when pressing enter I am actually creating a new row(see jquery function).

**EDIT**:

Printing  $_POST gives me this:

```
Array ( [0] => serial1 ) Array ( [0] => imei1 ) serial2imei2serial3imei3serial4imei4
```

I am looping like this:

```
$myArray = $_POST;
foreach ($myArray as $index) {
    print_r($index);       
}
```

**Edit**
Prepared statement:

```
$serial_no = e($_POST['serial_no']);
$imei = e($_POST['imei']);
$entrycount = count($serial_no);
$sales_date = date("'Y-m-d H:i:s'");
$cus_id = "1";

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO devices (serial_imei,serial_no,type_id,cus_id,sales_date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
for ($loop = 1; $loop <= $entrycount; $loop++) {
    $stmt->execute([$imei[$entrycount]], [$serial_no[$entrycount]], 1, $cus_id, $sales_date);
}
$pdo->commit();
```

Comment: Don't use `id` on your fields just `name`. Add `[]` to the name, so it looks like `serial_no[]`. Add the new input fields like that and when the form is submitted you will get an array of the values that were entered.

Comment: @Dave thanks for your answer, I tried but what I receive in PHP in empty, does not contain anything.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code you are using to process the form. That format does indeed work believe me :)

Comment: @Dave I just added the PHP code , how I am receiving that for submitted.

Comment: That's your submit button. Do a `print_r($_POST);` and you will see all of the data that was posted by the form. If you still don't see anything just do the print_r outside of the if statement.

Comment: @Dave thanks, I do receive data in PHP now. How would you put those two arrays together (serial_no[] and imei[]) and loop through them in PHP because I need to post them to DB? Note: each row has one serial_no and one imei but in case one of them is empty I need to notify the user.

Comment: If they are required then add `required` to the input statement so the form can't be submitted without them being completed. In PHP simply check the `count` of both arrays and if they don't match you don't have everything you need.

Comment: From the looks of it you haven't changed all of the `name` instances to be `name[]`. There should not be a number after the name any longer. Regardless, you appear to be on the right track. If the count of both arrays is the same loop through one of them and extract the value from both arrays for insertion into your database table.

Comment: @Dave the number in all values is added by me , I basically wanted to be more clear by giving each row a number so, for ex. first row has these values: Serial 'serial1' and IMEI 'imei1'

Comment: Resist that temptation as it will become a nightmare trying to process the values. The arrays will be sequential and the first input field array position will have a corresponding 2nd input field array position and value. You gain nothing by trying to give the names extra numbers or other values.

Comment: @Dave I found the mistake, I forgot indeed to change the `name` to `name[]`. Now, I am at the part where I need to INSERT into the Database, however, I dont know how to separate IMEI values from SERIAL values. Can you post an answer with this explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form will post 2 arrays that contain the values of `serial` and `imei` from your form. After you've verified that they have the same number of entries you just need to loop through one of them to extract the values from both arrays and insert them into your database.

Since your question did not include anything related to your database connection I can only show you the variables that you will use to insert the data into your DB. Use PDO and prepare the insert before entering the loop ([here's a good reference](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) to get you going with PDO and prepare).

```
$serial_no  = $_POST['serial_no'];
$imei       = $_POST['imei'];
$entrycount = count($serial_no);

for ($loop = 1;$loop <= $entrycount; $loop++) {

    // 
    // The values from your form will be in the following variables:
    //
    //
    // $serial_no[$entrycount]
    // $imei[$entrycount]
    //
    // The variables shown above are what you will have to insert into your DB.
    //
}
```

Comment: thanks! How do you get `count($serial)` because I tried like `$serials = $_POST['serial_no']` but I cant get anything.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't shown extracting the post arrays into variables.

Comment: I have added prepared statement to my question , do you think its properly set?

Comment: Doesn't succeed :(

Comment: Then you have a different problem/issue. Research the error being thrown and, if needed, start a new question.

Comment: actually, I just found out that there is something wrong with the arrays, they are empty! I dont receive anything at all from `$_POST['serial_no']` nor `$_POST['imei']` .

Comment: Well FWIW the original form you posted in your question has 2 `<form` lines which is probably not what you wanted.

Comment: I removed one of them but still the same problem.

Comment: just tried printing `$_POST['imei']` and I can actually print it but I cant print `$imei[$entrycount]`, it prints nothing.

Comment: You saw the modifications I made to my answer right? `$imei` gets created from this line `$imei       = $_POST['imei'];`.

Comment: yea of course, I meant I can print this `$imei = $_POST['imei'];`but not `$imei[$entrycount]`.

Comment: If you do a `print_r($imei);` you should see each of the input field values and they should be indexed by a number starting with zero. Which is what the for loop is for. To go through each of those values.

Comment: tried to print with print_r but it displays nothing, and I tried with a foreach loop ( `foreach($serial_no as $sr)`and I print `print_r($serial_no)` and `print_r($imei)` which are the arrays outside of the loop and they print correctly but if I try `print_r($sr)` it prints only the first value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213183/discussion-between-dave-and-rtzr).